# Specific file in bind-mount directory does not update in Docker container when editing on host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to develop a project locally using Docker Compose and to prevent re-building my image on every update, I've added a `bind-mount` that maps my `src` directory to my `WORDIR` in Docker. All changes made on my local machine are then reflected in my Docker container...EXCEPT for one file. For some reason, there's a single file in my project, that when I change its contents, the change is not reflected in the Docker container even though other files adjacent to this file DO detect file changes. Which leads me to believe that the directory is mapped correctly but it's some other issue with the file itself?

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
graphql:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./app/graphql/src/Dockerfile
    target: development
  volumes:
    - ./app/graphql/src:/workspace
    - /workspace/node_modules/
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# ------------> Base Image
FROM node:14 AS base

WORKDIR /workspace

COPY ./app/graphql/src .

# ------------> Development Image
FROM base AS development

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I haven't figured out how to show directory structure but the files that I am modifying are located in:

```
/app/graphql/src/api/graphql
```

Where file `a.ts` detects changes and is reflected in the Docker container but `b.ts` does not. I read about how Docker depends on the inode of the file to match if bind mounting specific files. I'm mounting a directory, but for a sanity check, I ran:

```
ls -i
```

in both the host and container and confirmed that the inodes matched.

I have two M1 Mac computers and I confirmed that this is a problem between both machines.

Any additional thoughts to debug this problem? My only other thought is that I hit a max number of files that can be tracked, but that's why I removed the `node_modules`. Any assistance would be really helpful!

---

EDIT: I created a new file, `c.ts` and duplicated the contents of `b.ts` (the file that wasn't changing between host and container)...and `c.ts` detects changes properly! Is there a way to inspect why a certain file isn't broadcasting changes? This is so strange.

Comment: Some hot-reload tools won't reload a file unless it's used somewhere. Is `b.ts` being imported somewhere?

Comment: @NickODell hey! yea I'm not sure if you saw my edit at the bottom, but adding a `c.ts` and copying over the code from `b.ts` (so it performs identical), causes hot-reload for `c.ts`. I had to run `docker compose down`, delete `b.ts` and re-add `b.ts` to my directory, then run `docker compose up` AND NOW it works. Could there have been specific file permissions or something affecting the host from changing files in the container? I can still debug this on my other computer

Comment: WRT permissions: If you do an `ls -l b.ts`, in the permissions field, in the first three characters corresponding to user permissions, do you have an 'r' there, for read permissions?

Comment: I see `-rw-r--r--` which I think is what we want, right? All the other files in that directory have the same permissions and those and detected by hot reload correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `COPY ./app/graphql/src .` directive from your Dockerfile  because this folder will mounted to container as volume.

Comment: I think that wouldn't cause the behavior the asker is seeing, though. Bind mounting over existing files shadows the old files: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container I agree that the step is unneeded, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, removing the `COPY` from my `Dockerfile` just causes an `EN0ENT` after running `docker compose up` since it cannot find any of my files :(